# facebook like status update with php

Tags: php, facebook

how can i make a page just like facebook status updates where user can see their friends activity?

If i have two tables one for users and other for friends the the user can see others activity those are in his friends list. How can i do that?

Comment: where did you learn to punctuate...............??

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a status update application, you don't have to build it from scratch if you don't wish to. Start with a functioning open source status update project like:

> #### "[StatusNet](http://status.net/) is the open source micro messaging platform that helps you share and connect in real-time within your own domain."
>
> *StatusNet is implemented with PHP/MySQL

and learn from it and/or adapt it.

Resources for a non-trivial social network architecting endeavours:

- http://blog.neo4j.org/2009/09/social-networks-in-database-using-graph.html
- http://www.bestechvideos.com/2009/03/29/facebook-science-and-the-social-graph
- http://bret.appspot.com/entry/tornado-web-server
- http://code.google.com/apis/socialgraph/docs/examples.html
- http://pinaxproject.com/
- http://elgg.org/